# Not able to configure Allure reports with Bamboo with allure for bamboo plugin

Tags: bamboo, allure

Could you please guide me about integration of Allure with Bamboo. I am trying with below versions to integrate:

Atlassian Bamboo version: 5.9.10

Allure for Bamboo: Version 1.7.0 • Bamboo Server 5.10.3 - 6.5.0

Allure Plugin: Version 1.1  • Bamboo Server 5.13.2 - 6.0.5

I've installed the first version of Allure Plugin, the v1.0, but I was not able to configure anything from the tool. I've also checked on a deployment projects if there was an Allure option available to use, but I didn't see anything neither. About installing the binary on bamboo's server, I'm not able to do that, and without that I'm not able to generate the necessary capability for this plugin. Also the documentation said that we can allow Allure to automatically update the binary, but all the modules from this plugin are enabled and no one of them says anything about letting bamboo to update the binary.

I am able to generate allure reports locally, Please help me for how to generate allure reports with bamboo .

Answer (score 0):

As the version of Allure Plugin supports Bamboo 5.13+, it is recommended that you [upgrade Bamboo](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-upgrade-guide-720411366.html) to the latest supported version, so that you can contact the respective vendor when you encounter issues.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However we have allure plugin v1.0 jar  which will support to Bamboo Server 5.0 - 6.0.5 as per given in document which you will find on https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1212541/allure-plugin/version-history. but while creating necessary executable, the Allure type never appears. I think this problem is with allure plugin v1.0 only. with V1.1 it is working fine. please correct me if I am missing something.